# How do I enclose each table column of a particular row in parenthesis

Tags: tables

I am a novice in Latex and have very little idea about writing latex macros. I have a collection of hundreds of tables to be incorporated in a document. In each table I need to have certain rows appear in italics and non-empty column values in parenthesis. I was able to make the row in italics by taking help of a number of posts in this forum. I am stuck with the second part. What will be the best way to do it using Latex macros? Below is the MWE replicating the problem...

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{6}{6}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{ +r^r^r }
\toprule\addlinespace
$\alpha$ & $\beta_1$ & $\beta_2$
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
0.00057 & -0.42643 & 0.02243
\\
\rowstyle{\itshape}
3.57 & -2.00 & 
\\\addlinespace
0.11157 & -0.42 & 0.025
\\
\rowstyle{\itshape}
4.87 & & 7.00 
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\caption{Sample Output}
\end{longtable}

Desired output (Added parenthesis manually)


\begin{longtable}[c]{ +r^r^r }
\toprule\addlinespace
$\alpha$ & $\beta_1$ & $\beta_2$
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
0.00057 & -0.42643 & 0.02243
\\
\rowstyle{\itshape}
(3.57) & (-2.00) &
\\\addlinespace
0.11157 & -0.42 & 0.025
\\
\rowstyle{\itshape}
(4.87) & & (7.00)
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\caption{Sample Output}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A side question: What are you trying to achieve with the instruction`\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{6}{7}`?

Comment: @Mico, it controls the font sizes for mathematical expressions, like inline, text, superscript and subscript

Comment: That's not quite right. The four arguments of the macro denote `{display size}`, `{text size}`, `{script size}`, and `{scriptscript size}`. It's somewhat unusual, to put it politely, to want to make second-level subscripts and superscripts *larger* than first-level subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: @Mico, you are correct. I mistook scriptscriptsize as subscriptsize. I have corrected the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this macro `\mytable`:

```
\def\tabrule{\noalign{\medskip\hrule\medskip}}
\def\normaltabitem#1{\ \hfil$#1$\ }
\def\specialtabitem#1{\ \hfil\def\tmp{#1}%  
   \ifx\tmp\empty\hfil\else(${\it#1}$)\fi\ }
\let\tabitem=\normaltabitem
\def\specrow{\noalign{\global\let\tabitem=\specialtabitem}}

\def\mytable#1{\halign{\tabitem{##}&\tabitem{##}&\tabitem{##}%
   \global\let\tabitem=\normaltabitem \cr #1\crcr}}

\mytable{  
   \tabrule
   \alpha & \beta_1 & \beta_2 \cr
   \tabrule
   0.00057 & -0.42643 & 0.02243 \cr
   \specrow 3.57 & -2.00 & \cr
   0.11157 & -0.42 & 0.025 \cr
   \specrow 4.87 &  & 7.00 \cr
   \tabrule
}
```

Comment: the suggested approach will require massive changes in the table data portion. I have hundreds of them in separate files and it will be difficult to the changes. Is there any way \rowstyle macro can be rewritten to accomplish what I am looking for? This will require change only at one place and everything else will remain unchanged. I am using \input to bring the table data tex files in the main tex file.

Comment: You needn't to change data area. This implies that you need to re-define the `\itshape` macro? And note the bad "minus" in your output because of math mode isn't used.

Comment: I am just a beginner user of latex, hence I am not capable of writing or rewriting `\itshape` macro. Also regarding the bad "minus" sign, I am having the same (mis)understanding. Can you help, please?

Comment: @kishore It is simple to declare `\\` like `\cr`, `\midrule`, `\toprule` etc. like `\tabrule`. Then the table data using `\mytable` will be more similar to your example. But if you need exactly the same source as in your example then you must re-define `\itshape` or `\rowstyle`.

Comment: I will try to modify `\itshape` or \`rowstyle` macro. Since I have never written a latex macro before, it will be very helpful if you can explain your code for `\specrow` macro and other associated macros, it is calling.